# Prisma include as a parameter

Tags: typescript, prisma

I'm transitioning from TypeORM to Prisma.

`TypeORM`

```
const user = await getUser("123", ["car", "car.wheels"])
static async getUser(
    userId: string,
    relations: string[]
  ) {
  return await UserEntity.findOne(
    {
      where: {
               id: userId
             },
      relations: relations
    }
  )
}
```

In Prisma, it uses `include` to get table relations. How would I pass variable relation into Primsa function?

Comment: What problem are you encountering in your attempt?

Comment: @caTS - Prisma uses a dictionary structure for the include argument. I'm not sure how to pass that in

Answer (score 0):

This is how , currently we do it,
you need to map your relations string[] to dictionary structure

```
 // define your variable with default includes
    const userInclusion = <Prisma.UserEntityInclude >{ include1: false, include2: false };
    // map from your string relations to dictionary 
    relations?.forEach(value =>{
     userInclusion[value as keyof typeof userInclusion] = true;
    })
  let args: Prisma.UserEntityFindUniqueArgs = { where: { id: userId } };
  if (relations.length > 0) {
            args = {
                ...args,
                include: userInclusion
            };
        }
     }
  const user = await UserEntity.findOne(args);
```